# Reporte con rotativa no funciona en publicación con Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, azure, rotativa

Tengo mi proyecto .net framework publicado en Azure. Estoy utilizando Rotativa para generar un reporte y descargarlo en pdf. Esto funciona de forma local pero al publicarlo no lo descarga, queda cargando hasta que muestra error por exceso de tiempo. También me muestra un error en Visual Studio al realizar la publicación, pero no me especifica cual es el error.

Supongo que es un problema de permisos de Azure, pero no sé como solucionarlo. Alguna idea?

Método en el controlador:

```
public ActionResult ImprimirReporte(string nomProductor, string nomCultivo)
    {
        ViewBag.pdf = true;
        return new ViewAsPdf("ResultadoFiltros", repoCultProd.PorFiltros(nomProductor, nomCultivo))
        {                
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            FileName = "Reporte Cultivos Por Productor.pdf"                
        };
    }
```

Error en Visual al publicar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la salida no muestra ningún error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error en el navegador al intentar descargar el pdf:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Paula, tu pregunta es un simple comentario, si no agregas algo de lo que hiciste o en la salida del visual studio, es complicado de ayudar. Es mas menos como decir mi auto hace un ruido en el motor cuando lo enciendo, alguien sabe que sucede?

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Ya lo edité, ahora es mas claro?

Comment: al publicar la app no te lanza ningun error como comentabas en tu pregunta, o por lo menos el visual no te dice ningun incorrecto en la imagen. Segundo, que tipo de servicio estas usando en azure para hostear tu app.

Comment: No, solo me muestra ese error que puse en la captura. Estoy usando el servicio de azure para estudiantes, que me da 100 creditos gratuitos.

Comment: Error 500 es cuando hay un error en el server, para ver el error real tendrías que manejarlo ya sea con un try catch y mostrándolo en la vista o agregando algún logger a tu aplicación como log4net y creando una archivo de texto .log, mientras que no tengas el error real... es muy difícil ayudarte con una solución.  Implementa log4net en la pagina para que obtengas los errores reales.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-log4net-in-asp-net-mvc-application/

Comment: Azure tiene muchos servicios, no importa que uses para estudiantes, eso es solo gratis y sigue sin decirnos nada.